# Error while moving the file from one folder to another using shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to look for 'jpg,jpeg,png' files in my USB drive and trying to move them one by one to a new folder. when i try to move it manually one file, it works but when i run the following program it fails. Please let me know whats the problem here.

```
import re
import os
import ntpath as path
import shutil

path="E:\\Mac"

newpath="E\\Mac\\MovedPics"


os.chdir(path)
expr=r'\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)$'

for file in os.listdir(path):

    if os.path.isfile(file):
       match=re.search(expr,file)
       if match:
          abspath=os.path.abspath(file)
          print('REGEXP MATCHED :-',abspath)
          move=shutil.move(abspath,newpath)
          if move:
             print('MOVE SUCCESSFUL :-',file)
          else:
             print('MOVE FAILED:-',file)
             break
    else:
       print('DESTINATION DIR ',newpath, ' DOESNT EXIST', file,':', os.getcwd())
```

Error:-

DESTINATION DIR  E\Mac\MovedPics  DOESNT EXIST voice_instructions_imperial 2.zip : E:\Mac
DESTINATION DIR  E\Mac\MovedPics  DOESNT EXIST usbpicsdata.txt : E:\Mac
REGEXP MATCHED :- E:\Mac\tattoo4.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:\Mac\tattoo4.jpg' -> 'E\Mac\MovedPics'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 7, in 
    move=shutil.move(abspath,newpath)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E\Mac\MovedPics'

> > > 

Comment: when i try to move that file manually, it works.                                                                                         >>shutil.move('E:\\Mac\\tattoo4.jpg','E:\\Mac\\MovedPics')
'E:\\Mac\\MovedPics\\tattoo4.jpg'
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing `:` in `newpath`:

```
newpath="E:\\Mac\\MovedPics"
          ^
```

BTW, you can use raw string literal (you can avoid escaping backslashes):

```
newpath = r"E:\Mac\MovedPics"  # == "E:\\Mac\\MovedPics"
```

Comment: Thanks. Cant believe i missed that.